# Как сравнить две таблицы?

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

**Используется**
C#
MySql

**Имеется**
Таблица 1 - редактируемая
Таблица 2 - шаблон

**Сценарий**
В процессе работы программы таблица "Таблица 1" подвергается редактированию.
Редактирование может заключаться в следующем:
- в "Таблица 1" количество записей **равно нулю** (т.е. пуста); 
- в "Таблица 1" количество записей **больше** чем в "Таблица 2";
- в "Таблица 1" количество записей **меньше** чем в "Таблица 2";
- в "Таблица 1" содержание записей **отличается** от "Таблица 2";

Количество и наименование столбцов всегда одинаково в обеих таблицах.

**Вопрос**
Как отследить несоответствия в "Таблица 1" по отношению к "Таблица 2"?
Состав несоответствий:
- 1. в "Таблица 1" количество записей **равно нулю** (т.е. пуста);
- 2. в "Таблица 1" количество записей **больше** чем в "Таблица 2";
        В результате вывести лишние записи таблицы "Таблица 1"
- 3. в "Таблица 1" количество записей **меньше** чем в "Таблица 2";
        В результате вывести записи которые есть в "Таблица 2", но отсутствуют в  "Таблица 1"
- 4. в "Таблица 1" содержание записей **отличается** от "Таблица 2";

**Таблицы**

Таблица 1 (редактируемая)

```
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+  
|  ID_ТБЛ|          pole_1 |          pole_2 |          pole_3 |   
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+  
|      1 | pole_1_запись_1 | pole_2_запись_1 | pole_3_запись_1 |   
|      2 | pole_1_запись_2 | pole_2_запись_2 | pole_3_запись_2 |   
|      3 | pole_1_запись_3 | pole_2_запись_3 | pole_3_запись_3 |  
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Таблица 2 (ШБЛ)

```
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+  
| ID_ТБЛ |          pole_1 |          pole_2 |          pole_3 |   
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+  
|      1 | pole_1_запись_1 | pole_2_запись_1 | pole_3_запись_1 |   
|      2 | pole_1_запись_2 | pole_2_запись_2 | pole_3_запись_2 |   
|      3 | pole_1_запись_3 | pole_2_запись_3 | pole_3_запись_3 |  
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: @alexander barakin  я человек неопытный, не могу понять в чём разница между вопросами.. Или эту тему нужно рассматривать как 4-е отдельных вопроса?

Comment: да, вы совместили несколько вопросов (как минимум три абсолютно не связанных друг с другом), которые надо было задать по отдельности. конечно, свою проблему (одну) вы решили. а вот другим, ищущим каждый из вопросов **по отдельности**, эти простыни вопроса и ответа будут, скорее всего, малополезны. т.е., для базы знаний, которой является сайт, и ваш мега-вопрос, и мега-ответ на него — больше похожи на балласт, чем на полезное содержимое. менять уже что-нибудь поздно. просто учтите, пожалуйста, на будущее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - 1. количество записей равно нулю (т.е. таблица пуста);

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2;
```

> - 2. количество записей больше чем в "Таблица 2";
> - 3. количество записей меньше чем в "Таблица 2";

```
SELECT CASE WHEN c1>c2 THEN 'В таблице 1 больше записей, чем в таблице2'
            WHEN c1<c2 THEN 'В таблице 1 меньше записей, чем в таблице2'
            ELSE            'Да всё нормально с количеством записей'
            END diag
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) c1 FROM table1) t1,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) c2 FROM table2) t2
```

> - 4. содержание записей (одна, несколько, все) отличается от записей "Таблица 2";

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1,table2 t2
WHERE t1.id=t2.id
  AND     (t1.pole_1,t1.pole_2,t1.pole_3) 
  NOT IN ((t2.pole_1,t2.pole_2,t2.pole_3))
```

**UPD:**

> - 2. в "Таблица 1" количество записей больше чем в "Таблица 2";
>        В результате вывести лишние записи таблицы "Таблица 1"

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

> - 3. в "Таблица 1" количество записей меньше чем в "Таблица 2";
>        В результате вывести записи которые есть в "Таблица 2", но отсутствуют в "Таблица 1"

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table2 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: скорректировал вопрос. В частности по п.2, п.3. Буду признателен если рассмотрите

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вам нужен провайдер данных, например [MySql connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.2.html). Скачайте и добавьте в проект.
Подключайтесь к базе данных используя скачанную библиотеку.

```
string myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=12345;database=test;";
conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
conn.Open();
```

Напишите команду, используя SQL из соседнего ответа, либо запросите таблицу полностью и сравнивайте уже в коде.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
cmd.Connection = conn;
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Считывайте результат построчно, можно, например, в `List`.

```
var result = new List<object>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    result.Add(new {reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]});
}
```

Уходя, выключайте свет.

```
conn.Close();
```